# How to color text

Tags: php, html, colors, echo

I have this code and the sad thing is i can't change anything or add outside the class `STUDENT`. I can modify only inside `STUDENT` and i can't alter the private fields. However I need to display the value of the field `$nume` in *red* color. Ideas?

```
class STUDENT {
    private $nume,$prenume;
    // Constructor 
    public function __construct($nume , $prenume){ 
        $this->nume=$nume;
        $this->prenume=$prenume;            
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->nume.".".$this->prenume;

    }


}

$student = new STUDENT("mr","Jack");  
echo "student: ". $student ."<hr/>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
public function __toString(){
    $red = '<span style="color: red;">' . $this->nume . '</span>';
    return $red.".".$this->prenume;

}
```

?

Comment: this is very good. how can i set the colored text to be bold? thank you. and thanks to all.

Comment: with the risk of doing unlogic things..i did this: $red = '<span style="color: red">' .'<span style="font-weight: bold">'. $this->nume . '</span>'. '</span>'; And it's working.

Comment: With inline css you could also do it like this:
<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold">...</span>
It's better to use css in another file. Just look on the web how CSS is supposed to be written if you have an interest in that.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the properties public so you can access them from the outside like this:

```
class STUDENT 
{
    public $nume;
    public $prenume;

    // Constructor 
    public function __construct($nume , $prenume)
    { 
        $this->nume=$nume;
        $this->prenume=$prenume;            
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nume.".".$this->prenume;
    }
}

$student = new STUDENT("mr","Jack");  
echo "<span style='color:red'>student: ". $student->nume ."</span><hr/>";
```

Or if you need to keep the private you can create a function inside the class to output it:

```
class STUDENT 
{
    private $nume;
    private $prenume;

    // Constructor 
    public function __construct($nume , $prenume)
    { 
        $this->nume=$nume;
        $this->prenume=$prenume;            
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nume.".".$this->prenume;
    }

    public function displayNume()
    {
        echo "<span style='color:red'>student: ". $this->nume ."</span><hr/>"; 
    }
}
```

Which you can then access like this:

```
$student = new STUDENT("mr","Jack");  
$student->displayNume();
```

Comment: font is deprecated, is not it?

Comment: I would have used a css class instead most likely anyhow if I was writing it, but I am giving the OP answers based on the OOP nature of the question. I don't want to complicate this answer by adding in a css file, throwing in divs or the like. I hope that my answer got the root of the problem and the OP can work out how he wants to do the red bit :)

Comment: Well, you could just use `style` attribute, I don't think it is more complicated than that, but, however, more up-to-date. No offense.)

Comment: @Notulysses LOL. I honestly can't even remember the last time I tried to format something without sticking it into a CSS file. I have however changed it to a span and used a style attribute :)

Comment: Then +1 and my answer doesn't make sense)

Comment: this is very good too. sadly i need to respect the things outside class..like i said. i can't modify those. but when i get 15 reputation i will comeback and vote-up your answer. thank you.